# SharedPreferences gone after killing app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

SharedPreferences should not be removed when killing the app, but in my case it does. I have earlier used SharedPreference without gettings these problems. But for some reason my SharedPreference are removed when I kill the app. 
Here are the code to save:

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }
```

And to save a String:

```
SavePreferences("NAMEOFPREFERENCE", ("WhatToSave"));
```

And to load:

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);


sharedPreferences.getString("NAMEOFPREFERENCE", "");
```

What could possibly cause the problem?

Comment: Are you sure, Have u tried seeing on sdcard..

Comment: verify the name of the shared preferences and also the key of the preference. it's better to use constants to avoid typos.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works when I have not  killed the app.

Comment: Can the fact that I kill the Activity where I save the preferences right after I saved them explain this error?

Comment: when are you saving them? you should save the preferences after they are edited since you don't know when you activity will be closed.. (or how)

Comment: I am saving them as soon as the current is selected. No delay there.

Comment: What do you mean by "kill the Activity" ?   You know you aren't supposed to do that, right?

Comment: I am using a task killer like many other android users, or if I turn on and off my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you should you [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) with [application context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29):

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```